# Push database to heroku: how to use heroku pg:push

Tags: heroku, database-migration, heroku-postgres

I want to push my local postgresql database to heroku, using `heroku pg:push` command. The command looks like this: `heroku pg:push mylocaldb DATABASE --app sushi` according to the heroku document: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql.

Here is my local database info:

```
Name: mysitedb
User: bill
Password: bill
```

The DATABASE_URL environment variable in my machine is set to: `postgres://bill:bill@localhost/mysitedb`.

My app's name is `secure-gorge-4090`. I tried `heroku pg:push mysitedb DATABASE --app secure-gorge-4090`. The output was:

```
 !    Remote database is not empty.
 !    Please create a new database, or use `heroku pg:reset`
```

I was surprised that I have put nothing into my DATABASE. But I still ran `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` to reset my DATABASE. After that, I tried `heroku pg:push mysitedb DATABASE --app secure-gorge-4090` again but the output was still the same.

I tried `heroku pg:push postgres://bill:bill@localhost:8000/mysitedb DATABASE --app secure-gorge-4090`. The output was:

```
!    LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE is not a valid database name
```

I don't know how to use this command to move my local database to heroku. I need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Are you actually typing in the token `DATABASE` in your commands, or is that a placeholder you're using for this question? From the [docs you linked to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql):

```
Like pull but in reverse, pg:push will push data from a local database into 
a remote Heroku Postgres database. The command looks like this:

$ heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi

This command will take the local database “mylocaldb” and push it to the 
database at DATABASE_URL on the app “sushi”. In order to prevent accidental 
data overwrites and loss, the remote database must be empty. You will be 
prompted to pg:reset an already a remote database that is not empty.

Usage of the PGUSER and PGPASSWORD for your local database is also supported
for pg:push, just like for the pg:pull commands.
```

When you do `heroku config -a secure-gorge-4090`, you should see an entry for `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[SOME COLOR NAME]`. Make sure you're using whatever that token is instead of `DATABASE` in your commands.

Since you have a username and password on your local database, you also need to do the part mentioned about `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD`. Here's the example from the `pg:pull` docs:

```
$ PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=password heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

So you should do something like:

```
$ PGUSER=bill PGPASSWORD=bill heroku pg:push mysitedb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[SOME COLOR] -a secure-gorge-4090
```

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to this old unsolved question! I just typed `DATABASE` in my commands. In fact, `DATABASE` is already set as my default database -- `HEROKU-POSTGRESQL-VIOLET`. So the commands `heroku pg:push mysitedb DATABASE --app secure-gorge-4090` and `heroku pg:push mysitedb HEROKU-POSTGRESQL-VIOLET --app secure-gorge-4090` should have the same effect. Following your advice, I created a new database named `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT` and tried `PGUSER=bill PGPASSWORD=bill heroku pg:push mysitedb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT --app secure-gorge-4090`, but the same error occured.

Comment: Which error? You mention a "Remote database is not empty" error and a "LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE is not a valid database name" error.

Comment: Did you run a pg:reset on HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT?

Comment: thank you - when I run "heroku config:get -a secure-gorge-4090" i get a missing arguments exception --of course i am using my own app name

Comment: @BKSpurgeon try `heroku config -a secure-gorge-4090`, I think heroku changed the command since I wrote this? I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: @carols10cents I get `'PGUSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` please help

Comment: are PGUSER and PGPASSWORD path variables

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a old discussion but I had the exact same problem.  Though it's not quite as convenient, I managed to achieve this via pg:backups instead.

This is detailed pretty nicely on the [heroku support site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres)

Start by installing the free pgbackups addon:

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

Then backup the database using your local pg_dump utility (included in PostGreSQL distro)

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dmp
```

Then put that dump file somewhere URL-addressible (e.g. Dropbox) and run the heroku import(make sure it's double quotes for Windows):

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://dropbox.com/dYAKjgzSTNVp4jzE/mydb.dmp' DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Two things to note: WARNING: `heroku addons:add` has been deprecated. Please use `heroku addons:create` instead.
 !    Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "pgbackups".

Answer (score 3):

You need the following command

```
PGUSER=root PGPWD=root heroku pg:push (local database name) DATABASE_URL --app heroku (app name)
```

make sure that you have entered correct postgres username and password

Comment: I get 'PGUSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a lazy programmer and efficient so this is much more easier rather than paying for AWS backup store them in excel sheets.
This save cost and not use PUSH: PULL which is not efficient.

Using CMD as ADMIN to insert Excel data to Heroku Postgres Database.

Follow INSTRUCTION

```
1. OPEN CMD AS ADMIN

2. heroku pg:sql postgresql-rugged-08088 --app sample

3. CREATE TABLE SERIAL_T (  id SERIAL , SERIAL VARCHAR(50),  USE INT,    DEVICES TEXT[], PRINTED BOOLEAN,  PRIMARY KEY (id))

4. \COPY SERIAL_T (SERIAL, USE, DEVICES, PRINTED) FROM 'C:\Users\PATH\EXCEL-03-27-2021.csv' DELIMITER ','CSV HEADER;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me without any issues was

```sh
pg_dump -f database_output_name --no-owner --no-acl -U user_name name_of_your_local_database
```

- `database_output_name` name of the output file you can rename it whatever backup, database ...etc
- `user_name`: the postgres sql user_name mainly postgres
- `name_of_your_local_database`: is the name of your database: mydb or whatever the name you gave if you forgot it you can check in PgAdmin
- `pg_dump` I have export it to global path that is why I am using it like this, other ways you can call it with the absolute path ie: `C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump`

the grenerated ourput file shoule look something like this

```sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: alembic_version; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.alembic_version (
    version_num character varying(32) NOT NULL
);

...
```

Now run this command to create the database on heroku

```sh
heroku pg:psql --app heroku_app_name < database_output_name
```

If you want to reset your database you can run this command

```sh
heroku pg:reset -a heroku_app_name
```

Now you can check the database on heroku by clicking on postgres link
Please check this answer for more detail: [pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive while trying to import postgres database to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459136/pg-restore-error-unrecognized-data-block-type-0-while-searching-archive-whil/71852548#71852548)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who might be facing the problem of not being able to push their local postgreSQL to heroku (WINDOWS), hear me out

1. Create an Addon on Heroku using GUI or CLI
2. OPEN CMD AS ADMINISTRATOR
3. First, `dump` SCHEMA ONLY using `pg_dump -s -f <DB_OUTPUT_NAME_ONLY_SCHEMA> --no-owner --no-acl -U <USERNAME> <LOCAL_DB_NAME>`
4. SECOND, restore your db on heroku using `heroku pg:psql --app <APP_NAME> < <DB_OUTPUT_NAME_ONLY_SCHEMA>`
5. THIRD, `dump` **DATA ONLY** using `pg_dump -a -f <DB_OUTPUT_NAME_ONLY_DATA> --no-owner --no-acl -U <USERNAME> <LOCAL_DB_NAME>`
6. FORTH, restore your data on heroku using`heroku pg:psql --app <APP_NAME> < <DB_OUTPUT_NAME_ONLY_DATA>`