# Heroku pg:push command missing

Tags: database, heroku

I tried to push my database to heroku by doing `heroku db:push` which gave me the following error:

```
!    db:push and db:pull have been removed and replaced with pg:push and pg:pull.
!    For more information, please see:
!      devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull
```

So I tried `heroku pg:push` which gave me this error:

```
!    `pg:push` is not a heroku command.
!    Perhaps you meant `db:push` or `pg:ps`.
```

And `heroku help pg` gives

```
pg:credentials DATABASE  #  Display the DATABASE credentials.
pg:info [DATABASE]       #  Display database information
pg:promote DATABASE      #  Sets DATABASE as your DATABASE_URL
pg:psql [DATABASE]       #  Open a psql shell to the database
pg:reset DATABASE        #  Delete all data in DATABASE
pg:unfollow REPLICA      #  stop a replica from following and make it a read/write database
pg:wait [DATABASE]       #  monitor database creation, exit when complete
```

My app is on the cedar stack and here's the full command I'm using:

```
heroku pg:push my_local_name HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL --app my_app_name
```

Also tried the suggestion of adding on `pgbackups` but I still get the same error.

Comment: have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490938/push-database-to-heroku-how-to-use-heroku-pgpush , seems to exist, but you may need more input to the commadn

Comment: Could you paste the full command you're trying to use? (I mean something like heroku `pg:push yourlocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[COLOR_NAME] --app yourappname`)

Comment: just looked closer at your output from `heroku help pg`, try running `heroku addons:add pgbackups` ?

Comment: @miss-attitude I've added the command I'm trying and also tried adding on `pgbackups` but that makes no difference either.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I was using the heroku gem (on ruby 1.9) when I went to see if there was a difference between the gem on 1.9 and 2.0 I saw the deprecation notice. This now works as expected with the [heroku-toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installed and the gems removed.

Comment: Link to the deprecation notice for this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't even notice that the gem was still installed for myself. It definitely interferes (silently) with the toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

in your project's dir, after installing taps gem, you can try using

```
taps server `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` db db
```

to start a taps server, and then

```
taps push mysql://[usernme]:[password]@[host]/[database] http://db:db@localhost:500
```

to sync local db to heroku through taps