# Push local database data to heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, heroku-postgres

I was trying to push my rails project database to heroku's database.

I type this 
`heroku pg:push ReadingList_development DATABASE_URL --app calm-eyrie-9110`

(`ReadingList_development` is my local database name.)

However, it shows this error

```
sh: psql: command not found
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       psql failed. exit status 32512, output: "" (RuntimeError)
    Command:     heroku pg:push ReadingList_development DATABASE_URL --app calm-eyrie-9110
    Plugins:     heroku-legacy-taps
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.40.6 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    c131ced7e02d4080a3ff53e27d7bd983


    More information in /Users/Coda/.heroku/error.log
```

And here is **error.log**

```
Heroku client internal error.
psql failed. exit status 32512, output: ""
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:783:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:108:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:53:in `ensure_remote_db_empty'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:23:in `prepare'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:14:in `execute'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:371:in `push'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
/usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
Heroku client internal error.
psql failed. exit status 32512, output: ""
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:783:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:108:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:53:in `ensure_remote_db_empty'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:23:in `prepare'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:14:in `execute'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:371:in `push'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
/usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
Heroku client internal error.
psql failed. exit status 32512, output: ""
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:783:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:108:in `exec_sql_on_uri'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:53:in `ensure_remote_db_empty'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:23:in `prepare'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/pg_dump_restore.rb:14:in `execute'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:371:in `push'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
/Users/Coda/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
/usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>`
```

### Update

syndax should be like

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

I am not sure what `mylocaldb` and `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA` should be. When I type this

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app calm-eyrie-9110
```

it return

```
Unknown database: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL
```

Does `mylocaldb` should be the same name in `database.yaml`?

here is my `database.yaml` info

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ReadingList_development
```

Furthermore, I type `heroku config:get -a calm-eyrie-9110`

it return

```
!    Usage: heroku config:get KEY
!    Must specify KEY.
```

Comment: Coda have you seen this [SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490938/push-database-to-heroku-how-to-use-heroku-pgpush?answertab=votes#tab-top)?  Your syntax doesn't look quite right and this answer includes a few other tips as well.  Please upvote linked answer if this helps you otherwise update your post with what you try.

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Comment: @steveklein , I read that answer, but I still can't figure it out, I've updated my question.

Comment: `mylocaldb` should be `ReadingList_development`.  The post I referenced above provided steps to determine the name of your Heroku DB.

Answer (score 1):

`heroku pg:info` will either give you the color(`HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA`) like in the docs, or it will provide something like `postgresql-something-12345`

Either one of those will suffice in place for the heroku db