# Heroku Django DB connection

Tags: django, database, heroku

I have an eLearning application developed in Django and deployed on Heroku. But I am facing one issue that is the local testing data that I have created is not reflected on the Heroku server. My application is successfully been deployed and is working like a charm but I don't have data on the Heroku server. Like on my local machine I have a username and password to login into the application and it works well on my local system but not on Heroku, the form gets displayed but I cannot log in. The error is that the **data entry doesn't exist**. Even some static data which gets rendered onto the home page is also not displayed. Is there any command which I need to run to upload my data from the local machine to the Heroku server? I have already used this command `heroku run python manage.py migrate` and then also pushed the updated version of the project to the Heroku master branch with `git push heroku master` after doing the commit. But still, no data is reflected onto the server. I have also tried the command `heroku pg:push` but it gives me **missing two arguments error**. Can someone tell me what am I missing.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "the local testing data that I have created is not reflected on the Heroku server"—why would it be? You said it yourself: it's _local_ data. Different instances of the same application generally can (and _should_) have different data in their databases.

Comment: In any case, you generally have two options: create new data in your hosted instance or copy data from another database. There's also the option to use database fixtures to install some basic application-level data, e.g. to populate a list of provinces in your country or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push database to heroku: how to use heroku pg:push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490938/push-database-to-heroku-how-to-use-heroku-pgpush)

Comment: No this doesn't answer my question

Comment: "No this doesn't answer my question"—I think it _does_, especially coupled with my two previous comments.