# pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive while trying to import postgres database to heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, push, alembic

I was trying to import a local database to Heroku, I got inspired from this StackOverflow question [Push database to Heroku: how to use Heroku pg:push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490938/push-database-to-heroku-how-to-use-heroku-pgpush). The command I was running was

```sh
PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=mypassword heroku pg:push mydatabse_name DATABASE_URL -a myapp
```

I got this error `pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive`:

```sh
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383   
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
...
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "public.user"
pg_restore: creating TABLE "public.alembic_version"
...
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.alembic_version"
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
 !    pg_restore errored with 1
```

I wonder how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this issue by running this command

```sh
pg_dump -f database_output_name --no-owner --no-acl -U user_name name_of_your_local_database
```

- `database_output_name` name of the output file you can rename it whatever backup, database ...etc
- `user_name`: the postgres sql user_name mainly postgres
- `name_of_your_local_database`: is the name of your database: mydb or whatever the name you gave if you forgot it you can check in PgAdmin
- `pg_dump` I have export it to global path that is why I am using it like this, other ways you can call it with the absolute path ie: `C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump`

the grenerated ourput file shoule look something like this

```sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: alembic_version; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE TABLE public.alembic_version (
    version_num character varying(32) NOT NULL
);

...
```

Now run this command to create the database on heroku

```sh
heroku pg:psql --app heroku_app_name < database_output_name
```

If you want to reset your database you can run this command

```sh
heroku pg:reset -a heroku_app_name
```

Now you can check the database on heroku by clicking on postgres link

[image: heroku_preview]

you should see something like this, if the number of rows is 0 you probably have empty database.

[image: database heroku info]

### Connet to heroku database via PgAdmin

- Open your PgAdmin right click on Servers and create new server let us name it Heroku
- Now click on Connection tab and fill up those information, you can find them in the hroku app under settings scrool to **Config Vars** reveal vars=> `DATABASE_URL`

the format of database url is like so:
`postgres://user:password@host:port/database`
ex:
`postgres://unancmnpxrgkmp:ababd6bcfed84a29549c32278204762d41b04be284a8b81750cbb6d356f8bcc7@ec2-54-209-221-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d22q7soeu9pv6u`
So fill up the information like so

- Host name/address: host ie: `ec2-54-209-221-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
- Maintainace database: database ie: `d22q7soeu9pv6u`
- username: username ie: `unancmnpxrgkmp`
- password => password ie: `ababd6bcfed84a29549c32278204762d41b04be284a8b81750cbb6d356f8bcc7`

[image: PgAdmin new server]

Click on save now you should see something like this once you open your server. You should scroll down until you find the name of your database `d22q7soeu9pv6u` above, you can open it and check the tables, if you do not find it refrech, make sure you create everything correctly

[image: Pg Admin Heroku Server]

[image: Heroku your databse]

Yeeeees, finally ElhamdulilAllah :D